# Git - Push changes from two local machines to master

Tags: git

I have changes on two different machines and they are different to each other. How can I push them to remote `origin/master` without having conflicts.

I have this:

```
Local machine 1: changes A, B
Local machine 2: changes C
```

How can I push them to remote master and then pull back to both machines so I can have:

```
Local machine 1: changes A, B, C
Local machine 2: changes A, B, C
```

Comment: push on one machine, pull on the other (merging), push on the other, pull on the first.

Comment: Do I need to commit changes from first machine, and then pull from anohter.. I tried this but I got conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes hasn't conflicts between them it not exists any problem to get this history.

From machine 1:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

And then in machine 2:

```
git pull --rebase
```

If you execute git pull without **--rebase** your will have a merge commit in your history getting this:

Local machine X: changes A, B, **Merge-commit**, C

Answer (score 1):

If you have remote access to the repo on machine 2, assuming all changes are commited (A, B, and C are existing commits):

on machine 1:

- fetch and merge the changes from machine 2: `git checkout master && git pull machine2 master` (I'm assuming you have committed to `master` on both machines, it sounded like that)
- if you get conflicts, solve them and go on to produce the merge commit
- optionally verify that all functionality implemented in A, B, and C, works on machine 1
- push the merge commit to your remote: `git push origin master`

on machine 2:

- refresh your master: `git pull origin master`

"Without having conflicts" is not possible if the changes in A, B, and C change the same things. Git does an amazing job at solving conflicts that are solvable, if it does not want to do it for you in that case you have to look into it personally.